# Why does the "background-image" on the video tag work only if the "poster" attribute is set?

Tags: html

I am curious to know why is it that, i can set a background-image on a video tag only if the video has has a "poster" set first? Obviously, having both at the same time will result in two background images being displayed simultaneously, which makes it useless to even set the background-image property, but my point is that, why can't i just set the background-image property without having the "poster" attribute first?

Here's an example:

```
<video controls>

    <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/webm"> 

</video>
```

CSS:

```
video {
    background-image: url(https://www.cancer.org/content/dam/cancer-org/images/photographs/single-use/espresso-coffee-cup-with-beans-on-table-restricted.jpg);
    }
```

So, in this example, the thumbnail of the video is the first frame, and the background-image doesn't work.

BUT, if i add the poster attribute to the video tag, both, the poster and the background-image now work.

HTML:

```
<video controls poster="https://post.healthline.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/difference-between-tangerines-oranges-thumb.jpg">

    <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/webm"> 

</video>
```

So, why? Why is the "poster" attribute required for the background-image to work on a video tag?

Also, on a related note, at first i thought that, removing the video content itself should make the background-image work, so i set the preload to none, but that didn't change anything. Setting the preload to none without a poster attribute set does not make the background-image work, and if you have a poster set, then only the poster is shown in its default size, while the background-image still doesn't work.

```
<video controls preload="none" poster="https://post.healthline.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/difference-between-tangerines-oranges-thumb.jpg">

    <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/webm"> 

</video>
```

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Well, the real question is, why use `background-image` when you already have `poster`?

Comment: People recommended using it as a way to resize the thumbnail. How else to resize the poster?

Comment: Sounds like a different question. What you've asked above is an [XY Question](https://xyproblem.info), where you're asking a question that is incidental to your real question.

Comment: I can't open that website, but can you answer my question, or do i have to ask again?

Comment: You have to ask the first time. The current question does not ask anything about resizing, and the question it does ask has been answered.

Comment: Okay, but, if you know how to resize the poster, why can't you just tell me now, so i don't have to ask another question?

Comment: I don't know how. But considering you're getting answers *for free* from volunteers, why can't you spend a few minutes of your time to ask a question properly? That way, other people can get the knowledge too? Comments are not indexed by search engines; questions and answers are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it probably has to do with the fact that `<video>` is a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) and therefore outside the reach of CSS.

That it works when specifying the poster attribute may reflect a browser implementation detail--the poster frame is rendered as a non-replaced element and therefore can be styled--but I wouldn't count on that always being the case.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Can i ask you then, how do you resize the poster?